# Spring Boot Profiles Not Picking Properties Files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are working on Spring Boot 2.1.6 and we need to implement spring boot profile in our application

We have currently two property files application.properties and bucket.properties(s3 configuration) file in our project.

so we have created the two properties files resources/application-dev.properties and resources/bucket-dev.properties file for Dev environment.

We are passing the VM arguments in the below program -Dspring.profiles.active=dev so that it pickup the files correctly.

We are using XML based configuration and hence we are loading the property file using below definition.

```
<bean id="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
        <property name="locations" >
            <list>
                <value>classpath:application-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:bucket-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Above configuration is working fine and spring boot is able to pickup the files properly.

But  I want to create the below kind of folder structure in resources folder to segregate the files properly.

```
|
resources
        |dev
            |
            application-dev.properties  
            bucket-dev.properties
```

As soon as I do that I have made changes in the above PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer like below.

```
<bean id="applicationProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
        <property name="locations" >
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${spring.profiles.active}/application-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:${spring.profiles.active}/bucket-${spring.profiles.active:dev}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

As soon as I start the application using the above configuration it is failed to locate the properties define inside the above file and failing to start App.

Please let me know what I am missing in the above configuration.

Note: We are not using Annotation based configuration in Spring Boot App but using only XML based configuraton.

Comment: This is like saying you have a car with both automatic and manual transmission at the same time. You should not be configuring the `application-*.properties` (at least) *at all*; that's *entirely* a job that Boot does.

Comment: that is not possible. In That case, You have to write the code yourself to load from that directories using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. you can try with `--spring.config.location` option. But I doubt it will work

Comment: @pvpkiran I tried the option—spring.config.location but it is not working. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: As I said before you have to use ProperyPlaceholderConfigurer and load the properties files yourself and provide it to Springboot. If you are okay to do so. I can put an answer

Comment: pvkiran please go ahead. I am okay with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Springboot will not do this out of the box, But you can use `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to do so.

```
@Configuration
public class PropertyFileLoaderConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertyFileLoaderConfig.class);

    private static final String PROFILE_DEV = "dev";
    private static final String PROFILE_STAGE = "stage";
    private static final String PROFILE_PROD = "prod";

    private static final String PATH_TEMPLATE = "classpath*:%s/*.properties";

    @Bean
    @Profile(PROFILE_DEV)
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer devPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Initializing {} properties.", PROFILE_DEV);
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(getResourcesFromPath(PROFILE_DEV)));//Loads all properties files from the path
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);

        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile(PROFILE_STAGE)
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer stagePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Initializing {} properties.", PROFILE_STAGE);
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(getResourcesFromPath(PROFILE_STAGE)));

        return configurer;
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile(PROFILE_PROD )
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer prodPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() throws IOException {
        LOG.info("Initializing {} properties.", PROFILE_PROD );
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources(getResourcesFromPath(PROFILE_PROD )));

        return configurer;
    }

    private static String getResourcesFromPath(String path) {
        return PATH_TEMPLATE.replaceFirst("%s", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: @pvkiran I have tried your solution.I have added the class DevConfiguration and passed the -Dspring.profiles.active=dev in startup. I have created the path resources/dev/application-dev.properties folder and placed my properties files but still spring boot still pickup the configuration from application.properties available in resources folder only. If I placed my files like this resources/application-dev.properties spring boot will pickup the correct property file based on environment passed.Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong over here?

Comment: Do you still need application.properties file. Just remove it

Comment: @pvkiran If I do that my application is not starting. Issue comes only if I place my properties files inside dev/application-dev.properties.In case I kept it under resources/application-dev.properties  and deletes the files application.properties it picksup the file based on passed spring.profiles.active VM argument. I dont understand why spring boot is failing to pickup the property under the specific folder.

Comment: does your code getting called or not? what if you keep an empty application.properties?

Comment: @pvkiran Thanks for your answer . I was able to make it work with above code after I added the below properties as my VM arguments -Dspring.profiles.active=<profilename>
-Dspring.config.location=file:<FolderPath>-Dspring.config.name=application,bucket

Comment: Good it worked. I forgot to mention.. you definitely need -Dspring.profiles.active. without that it won't work. I thought u r already passing that. But I don't think we need -Dspring.config.location.. do recheck